# How to write one method in one class or .swift file and call that method all over the code?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using `swift`. I have 10 view controller screen as well as 10 view controller.swift classes. And in each screen I am checking the Internet connection through my app. So I have a question.

I have one method say :

```
func somemethodchecking () {

}
```

I have written this method as `internetchecking.swift`. Now in my all other view controller under `viewDidLoad` I need to call that `somemethodchecking ()` method. But how should I do this? Do I need to import any procedure?

Comment: Please Check this https://www.dropbox.com/s/mwocafdnle7yye3/InternetCHeck.zip?dl=0 
use xcode 7.2

Comment: That's not a very smart design - you should put that stuff en a model class and call that same model from your viewcontrollers. Also, don't do potentially time consuming tasks in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Use extension - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html

Comment: Just in case you are looking for a drop-in solution: there is a development that combines the Apple's Reachability class with GCD: https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

Comment: Made a few text corrections to your post. Nothing to serious, but remember that having a good, clear question is the best way of getting the best help. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

First approach for this problem would be,as your's

write extension around your networking class,as below and call the method in all the viewdidLoad..

```
public extension Your_Networking_Class {
class func somemethodchecking()
{
    //your code
 }
}
                      OR

class  Networking_Extension
{
  class func somemethodchecking()
 {
    //your code
  }
 }
```

*You can call these methods in viewDidLoad as*

```
Your_Networking_Class.somemethodchecking()
Networking_Extension.somemethodchecking()
```

I hope all you need is to check if internet is available before making network call and show some error message to user,the better approach would be use broadcast-notification by making use of *Reachability*  class you can register for notification named *"kReachabilityChangedNotification"* and handle it instead of writing own code as apple all-ready provided you with such nice class, you can refer following doc for more detail..

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this,

1. Create Base class (inheriting from UIViewController class) and call your method in viewDidLoad - Automatically whenever "viewDidLoad" of child get call, parent class "viewDidLoad" also get call and so "somemethodchecking"
2. Create class level method and call it in viewDidLoad whenever you want
3. Notification - Use NSNotification class and send notification to internetchecking class by sending message "viewDidLoad" has been called. So that you can trigger "somemethodchecking"

Comment: Thanks for you solution.Can you please give me some code explain,I am new to ios dev

Comment: I have done your first option.Like say i have create one class inherit from uiviewcontroller.And inside that view controller under view did load i have put my code.But.......How can i call that view controller or method name to all my other view controller under viewdidload ???

Comment: I can understand little bit , but i am confused how could i call to all view controller screen ??..

Comment: Please make sure you are inheriting parent class and in child class you are calling     [super viewDidLoad] in  "viewDidLoad" of child class

Comment: I am asking how can i call that method to all view controller under viewdidload....Because in one screen i have done that coding under viewdidload know.Then how can i call that method to all view controller under viewdidload

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
class InternetUtils {
    class func isConnectionOk() -> Bool {
         //your code
    }
}
```

then, in your other classes, you could just do:

```
if InternetUtils.isConnectionOk() {
   //do online stuff
}
```

Comment: A nicer way of writing a utility wrapper in Swift is using a caseless enum, i.e `enum InternetUtils {...}` with `static` methods. That way you can't accidently create an instance of it and you don't get inheritance, you just get a namespace.